How to retrieve statistics from master node as tests are running
I am running Locust tests using distributed load generation with the flag:
--processes -1

I used to get the stats while the tests were running from
from locust.stats import get_percentile_stats_summary, get_stats_summary

This does not work any more, and it is just getting stats from different workers.  How can I get the combined stats directly from the master node while the tests are running?
Here is the code to access the stats:
class MyUser(FastHttpUser):
    wait_time = between(0.1, 0.5)

    def on_start(self):
        self._start_background_task()

    def _background_task(self):
        while True:
            print("Background task running...")
            request_stats = self.environment.stats
            # Calculate total requests
            num_requests = request_stats.num_requests


Can you show some more code? If you want to run something only on master you can check the type of the Runner: if isinstance(environment.runner, locust.runners.MasterRunner): ...

@Cyberwiz have updated the question with the code to access the stats, how can I access the Master stats in this case?

Use the test_start event. I havent actually run this, but it should be close enough :)
bg_task = None

def background_task(environment):
    while True:
        print("Background task running...")
        request_stats = environment.stats
        ...

@events.test_start.add_listener
def test_start(environment: Environment, **_kwargs) -> None:
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, locust.runners.WorkerRunner):
        bg_task = gevent.spawn(background_task, environment)

@events.test_stop.add_listener
def test_stop(environment: Environment, **_kwargs) -> None:
    bg_task.kill()

Check out https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/7c85b7988c643ee8f688c8bb6919272c38fbcf7b/examples/test_data_management.py for more examples.
